# C# Return a Calculated Distance between two Lat/Long Coordinates within a Linq Query WHERE statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, geospatial

I am trying to improve performance by moving a distance calculation into LINQ to SQL instead of performing the calculation on an enumerable. Specifically, I am trying to calculate distance in miles and filter for entities within  a 50 miles radius.

Here is my code (apologies for the lack of readability):

```
List<Thing> thing = _context.Things
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Where(t => (DbGeography.PointFromText(
      string.Format(
        "POINT({0} {1}",
        t.Latitude.Value, 
        t.Longitude.Value)
    ,4326)
   .Distance(
      DbGeography.PointFromText(
        string.Format(
          "POINT({0} {1}",
          other.Latitude.Value, 
          other.Longitude.Value),
      ,4326)
      * 0.000621371) <=50)
  .ToList();
```

Ultimately I will need to refactor this to an alternative that works in LINQ. Here is the error:

```
 System.NotSupportedException : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Stack Trace: 
DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
ExpressionConverter.TranslateIntoCanonicalFunction(String functionName, Expression Expression, Expression[] linqArguments)
SpatialMethodCallTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
ExpressionConverter.TranslateIntoCanonicalFunction(String functionName, Expression Expression, Expression[] linqArguments)
<27 more frames...>
ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
List`1.ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I have also tried this:

```
SqlGeography.Point(
  Convert.ToDouble(t.Latitude.Value),
  Convert.ToDouble(t.Longitude.Value),
  4326)
.STDistance(
  SqlGeography.Point(
    Convert.ToDouble(other.Latitude.Value), 
    Convert.ToDouble(other.Longitude.Value), 
    4326)) * 0.000621371) <= 50)
```

Same System.NotSupportedException for Linq to SQL translation.

Comment: I'd recommend you power up your db tables a little and store the lat long on a geography/point column, then use the EF support for spatial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Comment: Also want to note that when you use the XFromText methods to parse a WKT the points are in LONG LAT order, not LAT LONG, but when you use the normal constructors like geography::Point(lat,long,srid) they *are* LAT LONG.  It doesn't matter so much for your distance as you have it here because they both (consistently) wrong way round but it will if you eg were to put all the coords in properly to the table as geography Poonts and then accidentally create a point thousands of miles away because the lat/long are inverted..

Comment: I don't have much experience with LINQ-to-entities but I guess it tries to convert your statements into SQL and cannot find an equivalent SQL expression for `String.Format`. I also noticed that you are missing a `)` in `POINT({0} {0}`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by just concatenating the strings in DbGeography.FromText() (changed from DbGeography.PointFromText()). Also did have to reverse lat long to long lat.

```
DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + t.Longitude.Value + " " + t.Latitude.Value + ")"
,4326)
```